# How to change Paypal item name from WooCommerce order?

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, payment-gateway

I am using WooCommerce and Paypal gateway. I would like the Paypal order details to be different (best would be just the order number) from the item on the WooCommerce store. I tried codes i found on this website from 2+ years ago but they are not working.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an invoice prefix setting, within the settings of the PayPal payment method you are using in WooCommerce.

If there isn't such a setting, you will need to edit code to change it. What exactly will depend on what PayPal payment method for WooCommerce you are using. There are many available.